# Remove Function is making the program to crash c++

Tags: c++, class, linked-list

```
/********************************************
*   Remove the last employee from the list  *
********************************************/
void EmployeeList::Remove() 
{
    newEmployee * nextToEnd = head, 
                * last = head->Next();

    //THIS IS THE PROBLEM
    //no nodes
    if(head == NULL)
        return;

    //remove the only employee in the list
    if(head->Next()== NULL)
    {
        cout << "\n\t\tEmployee ID " << head->empID() << " and salary $" 
             << head->ySalary() << " have been removed.\n"; 
        head = NULL;
        delete head;
    }

    else
    {  
       // remove the last employee of the list
        while(last->Next() != NULL)
        {
            nextToEnd = last;
            last = last->Next();
        }   

       cout << "\n\t\tEmployee ID " << last->empID() << " and salary $" 
            << last->ySalary() << " have been removed.\n";  

        delete last;
        nextToEnd->SetNext(NULL);      
    }
}
```

having problem when trying to remove from an empty list. I know i cant remove if it is empty but i would instead of crashing the program to display "The Employee List is empty.

I specified where I think the problem hoping someone can help me out to figure it out.

Comment: What do you expect `head->Next()` to do if `head` is NULL?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All you have to do is what's already shown in the code. Notice how it outputs text to console using `cout`. Change the `if` statement where you specified the 'problem' is to output a message and then return.

But your program crashing has nothing to do with what you have marked. It is crashing because of `head->Next()`. You can't call a method on an object that is `NULL`. That should be occurring *after* the `if (head == NULL)` check.

Comment: //THIS IS THE PROBLEM
    //no nodes
    if(head == NULL)
    {
        cout << "\t\tThe Employee List is empty.\n"; 
        return;
    }

Comment: I COULDN'T UNDERSTAND THE SECOND EXPLANATION. YOU MEANT I CANNOT USE IF(HEAD->NEXT() == NULL)? WHAT CONDITION SHOULD I USE THEN?

Comment: @DestinyAlyshaCampos First of all, turn of caps lock. About the second part of my explanation, you said your program was crashing and I was explaining why. This is a problem for you: `last = head->Next();` and I have already explained why.

Comment: @DestinyAlyshaCampos , what Jonathon is saying is you do this: `last = head->Next();` before you test that it is safe to do so with `if(head == NULL)`. The solution is obvious: Change the order.

Comment: Thank you both JonathonOgden and user4581301 for helping me fix the errors! :-)